# After adding a couple packages I got this error. django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The INSTALLED_APPS setting must be a list or a tuple

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-cors-headers

after adiing the corsheaders and whitenoise packages to my api I got this error.

```
(venv) kawekaweau@Ground-Control:~/Desktop/GeeksGeckosAndGoodVibes/Geckos/Gekkonidae$ python manage.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kawekaweau/Desktop/GeeksGeckosAndGoodVibes/Geckos/Gekkonidae/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/kawekaweau/Desktop/GeeksGeckosAndGoodVibes/Geckos/Gekkonidae/manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/kawekaweau/Desktop/GeeksGeckosAndGoodVibes/Geckos/Gekkonidae/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 442, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/kawekaweau/Desktop/GeeksGeckosAndGoodVibes/Geckos/Gekkonidae/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 436, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/kawekaweau/Desktop/GeeksGeckosAndGoodVibes/Geckos/Gekkonidae/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 412, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/kawekaweau/Desktop/GeeksGeckosAndGoodVibes/Geckos/Gekkonidae/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 74, in execute
    super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "/home/kawekaweau/Desktop/GeeksGeckosAndGoodVibes/Geckos/Gekkonidae/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 458, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/kawekaweau/Desktop/GeeksGeckosAndGoodVibes/Geckos/Gekkonidae/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 81, in handle
    if not settings.DEBUG and not settings.ALLOWED_HOSTS:
  File "/home/kawekaweau/Desktop/GeeksGeckosAndGoodVibes/Geckos/Gekkonidae/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 102, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/home/kawekaweau/Desktop/GeeksGeckosAndGoodVibes/Geckos/Gekkonidae/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 89, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/home/kawekaweau/Desktop/GeeksGeckosAndGoodVibes/Geckos/Gekkonidae/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 234, in __init__
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The INSTALLED_APPS setting must be a list or a tuple.

  File "/home/kawekaweau/Desktop/GeeksGeckosAndGoodVibes/Geckos/Gekkonidae/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 81, in handle
    if not settings.DEBUG and not settings.ALLOWED_HOSTS:
  File "/home/kawekaweau/Desktop/GeeksGeckosAndGoodVibes/Geckos/Gekkonidae/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 102, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/home/kawekaweau/Desktop/GeeksGeckosAndGoodVibes/Geckos/Gekkonidae/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 89, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/home/kawekaweau/Desktop/GeeksGeckosAndGoodVibes/Geckos/Gekkonidae/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 234, in __init__
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The INSTALLED_APPS setting must be a list or a tuple.
```

following is my settings file. minus some stuff

```
"""


Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 4.2.2.


from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent



ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = {
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'whitenoise.runserver_nostatic',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'geckos.apps.GeckosConfig',
    'accounts.apps.AccountsConfig',
    'posts.apps.PostsConfig',
    'rest_framework',
    'corsheaders',
}



MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'Gekkonidae.urls'

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    "DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES": [
        "rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny",
    ],
}

CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = [
    'http://localhost:3000',
    'http://localhost:8000',
]


WSGI_APPLICATION = 'Gekkonidae.wsgi.application'
Django settings for Gekkonidae project.

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}



# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [str(BASE_DIR.joinpath('static'))]
STATIC_ROOT = str(BASE_DIR.joinpath('staticfiles'))
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'

CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ['http://localhost:3000']

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

AUTH_USER_MODEL = "accounts.CustomUser"
```

I tried adding a line to settings but to no effect
`INSTALLED_APPS = json.loads(os.environ.get('INSTALLED_APPS '))`
I have since went back to scratch and started searching old stack overflow posts and none have helped. even a bit of direction in the problem solving Arena would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Django requires `INSTALLED_APPS` to be defined as a list or a tuple but
currently your `INSTALLED_APPS` is defined as a dictionary. You can refer to the [documentation here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#installed-apps) for more clarity on INSTALLED_APPS setting.

Changing your `INSTALLED_APPS` in settings to the following will fix the error:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'whitenoise.runserver_nostatic',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'geckos.apps.GeckosConfig',
    'accounts.apps.AccountsConfig',
    'posts.apps.PostsConfig',
    'rest_framework',
    'corsheaders',
]
```

Comment: question is here why did he actually changed it.

Comment: Thank you so much and to answer I'mSRJ,  I didn't at least not intentionally.

Comment: Really glad my answer helped you. I would be grateful if you could mark it as accepted as well. @JonathanLang